# Verifying an implicit differentiation question (explanation required)

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Question 5 (ii) for this paper: http://sixthform.m34maths.com/A-level%20exams/c3/c309ju.pdf

I done the first part, and attempted part (ii), I came up to the second to last step but got stuck. The answer is in the mark scheme (scroll down in pdf file) however I just can't wrap my head around the last bit, an explanation would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the part where you're using the equation $e^{2y}=1+sin(x)$ to show $\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{2y}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with $e^{2y}=1+\sin x$, which you can represent as:
$$y=\frac12(\ln(1+\sin x))$$
deriving gives:
$$y'=\frac12\frac{(1+\sin x)'}{1+\sin x} = \frac{\cos x}{2(1+\sin x)}$$
but we know that $e^{2y}=1+\sin x$, so:
$$y'=\frac{\cos x}{2e^{2y}}$$

Comment: Oh that's much clearer than the mark scheme, I got confused because of the lack of brackets in the mark scheme and I forgot to substitute on the last step. Thanks for making it clearer :)